# How to avoid using specific pixel value on bottom property for ::after

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I've got a banner that when hovered on displays an "underline" at the bottom of the container. Currently it's achieved using `::after` and the functionality is perfect, but I don't like having to be so specific with the `bottom: -65px`, it feels a bit hacky and not truly responsive.

For example, if the banner was not exactly 150px, then the underline would be off.

Is there a way I can avoid using specific px values for bottom in this use case?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -65px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0%;
  content: '';
  color: transparent;
  background: black;
  height: 3px;
}

ul li a:hover::after,
ul li a:active::after {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to make the `a` elements take all the available height so you can specify `bottom: 0;` on the pseudo element like this :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.height-80 {
height: 80px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
}

ul li a::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0%;
  content: '';
  color: transparent;
  background: black;
  height: 3px;
}

ul li a:hover::after,
ul li a:active::after {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="banner height-80">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Another approach could be to use CSS variables to specify the height of the header and adapt the positioning of the pseudo element accordingly.

In the following example, you can change the height of the banner by changing the value of `--banner-height: 150px;` and the positioning of the pseudo element will adapt with `margin-bottom: calc(var(--banner-height) / -2);` (*note that y also changed the value of `bottom` to `50%`*).

```css
:root {
  --banner-height: 150px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner {
  height: var(--banner-height);
  background-color: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0%;
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--banner-height) / -2);
  content: '';
  color: transparent;
  background: black;
  height: 3px;
}

ul li a:hover::after,
ul li a:active::after {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: _"to make the a elements take all the available height"_ - then they will also react to the mouse cursor over the full height; if that is _not_ wanted, then only the `li` could be made full height, and `position:relative` moved from the `a` to the `li`, so that the latter set the "frame" for the absolute positioning of the pseudo element.

Comment: @CBroe indeed, that is a side effect (good or bad depending on the usecase) of the first technique I posted. The second one keeps the hover and click hitboxes the same as in OPs example.

Comment: Agreed, it's not ideal to have the hover state showing when a user is at the top of the container (above the link)

Answer (score -3):

The whole `::after` isn't nessecary.

You can use the `border-bottom` declaration:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #00000000;
}


ul li a:hover {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  border-bottom: solid 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Option 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Option 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Option 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, the results will differ. You can change the vertical position by editing `a`'s height.

This may be not what you're looking for, as the underline won't slide out, it will just "appear".

Comment: Back to the original problem with this answer though, as you'd need to specify a margin on the border!

Comment: @cts you can try to set a's height to 100%